# Why does the line `safecrlf = trueexport` keep getting appended to my .gitconfig file?

Tags: git, git-config

I have searched the bowels of the internet and have been unable to determine what could be going on here:

- For some reason, the line `safecrlf = trueexport` keeps appending to my `[core]` global .gitconfig settings
- It will often be appended multiple times
- This causes the following error when I try to run any git command: `fatal: bad boolean config value 'trueexport' for 'core.safecrlf'`

The rest of my .gitconfig is quite simple:

```
[user]
    name = myusername
    email = myemail@email.com
[core]
    editor = code --wait
    autocrlf = input
    safecrlf = true
    safecrlf = trueexport // here's the offending line
    safecrlf = trueexport // as you can see, in this instance it appended 4 times
    safecrlf = trueexport 
    safecrlf = trueexport

[color]
    ui = auto

[alias]
  co = checkout
  ci = commit
  st = status
  br = branch
  hist = log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short
  type = cat-file -t
  dump = cat-file -p

[init]
    defaultBranch = main
```

- I can resolve this error by deleting this setting, but it keeps reappearing
- I have not been able to identify any pattern that leads to the line getting appended
- It happens quite regularly, but once I delete the offending line I can generally use git with no issues for a bit, but again, there is no consistent pattern that I have been able to recognize (it's **not**, for example, something like "The line appears once a day and after deleting it I can use git for another 24 hours")
- I have tried adding and removing the following settings as well, but it doesn't seem to impact this behavior:

```
    autocrlf = input
    safecrlf = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a misbehaving program (or IDE plugin for Visual Studio Code or whatever) that runs `git config --global --add core.safecrlf trueexport`.  Find it and squash its bug.  (The problem is not in Git itself; this would have been found ages ago, if it were.)

I suspect the misbehaving program is supposed to read:

```
git config --global --add core.safecrlf true
export something
```

and somehow the `export` word from the subsequent line got pasted up against the `true` word from the `git config` line.